# how to you can add small symbol in top corner on key

Tags: java, android, ios, windows, android-studio

i want add symbols on left top keys like any keyboard averaibel now in stories 
like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vw34.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a little unclear: do you want to add this symbols on `ios`, `windows` or `android`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android you can't.  Keyboards are a separate app, and decide what keys to display on their own.  There is no API to even suggest special keys, much less force them.

Comment: OK . how I can create this spacial keys on my android studio ??